# How to find total number of reserved instances under particular tag?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, python, boto

I am query AWS using boto ec2 in python.
Firstly I find all reserved instances by `get_all_reserved_instances` then I am also able to find total count of each instance_type by `instance_count`. I am trying to calculate total number of reserved instances under tags.

Eg. We have two tags `group` and `name`.
Then I want to show total number of reserved instances of particular type (Eg. i2.xlarge) under `group` tag.
How to do this, I did not find this in AWS console also ?

Answer (score 0):

Each AWS instance item boto returns has `tags` and `instance_type`, that you can use for querying.

With boto, you can do something like below - I am using `get_all_instances` as I don't have any reserved instances under my account - but I believe the outcome should be similar in your as well if you replace it with `get_all_reserved_instances` -

```
import boto
conn=boto.connect_ec2()
R=conn.get_all_instances()
i=[i for r in R for i in r.instances]
for item in i:
  if item.instance_type=='i2.xlarge' and item.tags.get('Name')=='demo':
    ## Your logic here
```

Comment: If we iterate result return by get_all_instances(), its like,
for instance_set in R:
  for instance in instance_set.instances:
   ##logic

and we can print its name,tag etc.

But we iterate result return by get_all_reserved_instances() like this,
for instance in R:
 ##logic
and it does not has any attribute like .tags or .instances.
when i print instance in get_all_reserved_instances() , it print result like,
ReservedInstance:ah9l09kj-6s1a-4122-9lp7-237jks8901ka
ReservedInstance:jhaks0923j-8c0a-1275-0l29-8dhdkl98df34
How to identify that which reserve instance belong to which tag ?